# Match string anywhere in the string without using regular exp module

Tags: python

I am trying to match a string in a list. If the entered string exists anywhere in the string, in which the search is done, I want to return `True`. I know, it can be one by using `re.search` but I am trying to do that without the use of regular expressions module. I am trying to do it as simple as possible.

A trivial example could be:

```
drinks = ['cola_with_ice', 'icetea', 'lemonade', 'coffee']

if 'cola_with_ice' in drinks:
    print 'Requested drink or a variant of it exists'
```

However, I want my code to return `True` if, for example even 'cola' is entered:

```
if 'cola' in drinks:
    ...
```

I am wondering whether it is possible or not. I thought, it could be done, may be with the use of wildcards etc. ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> drinks = ['cola_with_ice', 'icetea', 'lemonade', 'coffee']
>>> any('cola' in drink for drink in drinks)
True
>>> any('apple' in drink for drink in drinks)
False
```

Comment: Thank you! I have must use a generator or iterator expression... I thought may be a wildcard or sth like that could be sufficient...

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `drinks` is a list, and you are searching for a substring of a string inside the list, so you will have to loop through the list (maybe using generator expression) as shown below:

```
drinks = ['cola_with_ice', 'icetea', 'lemonade', 'coffee']
if any('cola' in x for x in drinks):
    # your code
```